# How to prove that $\lim \limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$

Tags: limits, fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

How would one prove that
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}=\varphi$$

where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number and $\varphi$ is the Golden Ratio?

Comment: This is explained at the wikipedia page, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: Where is it on the page?

Comment: You will find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106049/another-way-to-go-about-proving-the-limit-of-fibonaccis-sequence-quotient) useful.

Comment: Read the ninth chapter of C. Stanley Ogilvy's magnificent book _Excursions in Geometry_.

Comment: Will do, thanks again.  I will need to look up this book in the library.  Thanks!

Comment: @Argon Your limit follows easily from the closed-form expression for $F_n$, the derivation of which is described in the section "Relation to the Golden Ratio".

Comment: @Matthew, yes, but I reckon that's overkill, when it comes so fast from the recurrence. Still, the more methods a person knows, the better.

Comment: @Gerry I wasn't disparaging your answer - it is excellent.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

$$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$$

$$F_{n+1}/F_n=1+F_{n-1}/F_n=1+1/(F_n/F_{n-1})$$

Call the limit $x$; then $$x=1+1/x$$

Take it from there.

Comment: @Gerry I think it is important to prove the limit exists, isn't it? i.e Considering even and odd subsequences and showing the sequence in general is bounded.

Comment: @PeterT.off, on principle, I leave details to the reader.

Comment: @GerryMyerson : You haven't up-voted the question yet.

Comment: @Michael How do you know who upvoted and who didn't? Or is the only upvote yours?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, perhaps you would like to start a meta thread (or direct me to an already existing thread) on the circumstances under which one is obligated to upvote a question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think Michael was making a joke, alluding to the fact that many users upvote questions that they have answered to attract more views and hence potential upvotes to their answer.

Comment: @Ragib, oh.${}$

Comment: The only up-vote at that point was mine (and still is now).  "Obligation" is not what I had in mind.  I just thought that if a question is worth answering, it's almost always worth up-voting.  This question is worth having for future reference by others who come to this site.

Comment: @Michael, I disagree with "if a question is worth answering, it's almost always worth up-voting," but this isn't the place to discuss it. It may be worth bringing up on meta (if you haven't already done so - I haven't checked recently).

Comment: @GerryMyerson : But this is the place to discuss what has happened in this _particular_ instance.

Comment: @Michael, I disagree with that, too. Try http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/why-should-i-upvote-questions

Comment: I will add to the above discussion between Gerry Myerson and @Michael Hardy that there is now this thread on meta: [About not upvoted, answered questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10919). (It is from 2013, so it did not exist at the time of the above exchange.)  There is also a related post on meta.SE: [Why don't people upvote questions they answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/509) (Posting mainly for the benefit of other users who see this post and are interested in the issue discussed in the above comments.)

Answer (score 20):

If you know that the limit exists, you can proceed e.g. as in Gerry's answer.

There are probably many different ways to show that the limit exists. 
One of them uses [Cassini identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities)
$$F_{n+1}F_{n-1}-F_n^2=(-1)^n,$$
you can get 
$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}=(-1)^n\frac1{F_nF_{n-1}}.$$

So now you could use [Leibniz test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test), you only have to show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{F_nF_{n-1}}=0$

(Proof of Cassini identity can be found on Wikipedia, on this site or elsewhere.)

Comment: How does the limit of 1/FnFn-1 = 0 imply that the limit of Fn+1/Fn exists? Please help ASAP.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, all you have to do is to use Leibniz test for the alternating series $\sum (-1)^n \frac1{F_nF_{n-1}}$.

Comment: Yes, that implies that the right side of the equation is equal to 0. but how does that imply that Fn+1/Fn exists?

Comment: Based on the above equality, you can notice that $\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n} = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=2}^n (-1)^k \frac1{F_kF_{k-1}}$. So the limit exists if and only if the series $\sum\limits_{k=2}^\infty (-1)^k \frac1{F_kF_{k-1}}$ converges.

Comment: Why is $$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}-\frac{F_n}{F_{n-1}}=(-1)^n\frac1{F_nF_{n-1}}.$$ the following $$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=1+\sum^n_{k=2}\ldots $$ ?

Comment: @pls_halp Try induction or [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 13):

Gerry's solution is quite elegant. One might take the less elegant route of first [deriving the Binet formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/65076):

$$F_n=\frac1{\sqrt{5}}(\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n})$$

from which

$$\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-(-\phi)^{-n-1}}{\phi^n-(-\phi)^{-n}}=\frac{\phi-\frac{\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^{n+1}}{\phi^n}}{1-\frac{\left(-\frac1{\phi}\right)^n}{\phi^n}}=\frac{\phi+\frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n+1}}}{1-\frac{(-1)^n}{\phi^{2n}}}$$

$(-1)^n$ is a bounded sequence, while $\frac1{\phi^n}$ decays nicely to $0$, so... you can take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Several useful and cogent answers have already been given to this question, both here and in at least [one duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286593/proof-the-golden-ratio-with-the-limit-of-fibonacci-sequence). However, I haven't seen anyone mention the most elegant, concise and enlightening argument I could find when I was wondering about the same thing, i.e. this [blog post](https://www.mctague.org/carl/blog/2017/11/27/golden-fibonacci-banach/) by Carl McTague. I'm just linking it here in hopes that others may enjoy it.