# What is the Limit of the following Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

The Fibonacci numbers $x_1,x_2,.......,$ are defined recursively by $x_1=1, x_2=2$ and $x_{n+1}=x_n+x_{n-1}$ for $n\geq2$. Show that, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ exists, and evaluate the limit.

Comment: Try using the matrix representation and the spectral theorem.  This is going to be fun.

Comment: Are you trying to do this without first establishing the formula for $x_n$?

Comment: This question is asked [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132305/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-fracf-n1f-n-frac)

Answer (score 4):

Define $a_n = \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

Then, you can show that $$a_{n+1} = \frac{x_{n+2}}{x_{n+1}} = \frac{x_{n+1} + x_n}{x_{n+1}} = 1 + \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} = 1+\frac1{a_n}$$

So you now have a function $f$ such that $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$.

Now you can use the standard methods for recursively defined sequences to prove that the limit $a$ exists and that if it exists, it satisfies the equation $a=1+\frac1a$

Comment: you should work out some details so OP can understand. rushing to post a solution is "counter productive" here...OP is not at your level...

Comment: @Ganymede I don't know the level of the OP, and neither do you. If my answer is above his level, he can ask me about it in the comment. I assumed he already knows how to deal with limits of the type $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$