# Two ٍEquations Defining the Golden Ratio Differently

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, golden-ratio

In most sources, the Golden Ratio has been referred to as: $\phi = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$. Nevertheless, in the book " *The Theory of Numbers, a Text and Source Book of Problems* ", by Prof. Andrew Adler and Prof. John E. Coury, it has been alluded to differently.

> ... For example, any two successive terms have no divisor in common
>   except 1, and the ratio of sufficiently large successive terms is
>   arbitrarily close to the "golden ratio" ($\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$),
>   which was of interest to the ancient Greeks ...
>
> *- The Theory of Numbers, a Text and Source Book of Problems*

I wish to know whether the both of them are correct or not? If yes, why?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132305/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-fracf-n1f-n-frac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Golden Ratio mentioned in the book is the reciprocal of the commonly used Golden Ratio
$$
\frac{\sqrt5-1}2\frac{\sqrt5+1}2=\frac{5-1}4=1
$$