# using limit properties how it becomes?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, number-theory, analysis, fibonacci-numbers

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n-1)L_{n+1}+\dfrac{(n-2)L_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{5}}{(n-2)L_n+\dfrac{(n-3)L_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}{5}}
\end{equation}

how it becomes
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{nL_{n+1}+nL_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{nL_{n}+nL_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}
\end{equation}

the denominator 5 is missing i used to algebraically manipulate it but why is it 5 is missing?

Comment: sorry the edited once is correct .

Comment: Hey there. You might find this interesting:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132305/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-n-rightarrow-infty-fracf-n1f-n-frac

Comment: Where does this manipulation come from?

Comment: in the article "fibonacci numbers of tadpole graph"

Comment: Ah, here: [Fibonacci number of the tadpole graph](http://www.ejgta.org/index.php/ejgta/article/view/82)

Comment: since it is going to phi the author of this paper remove 5 immediately in able to simplify the equation

Comment: Please see my answer to the same question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2557064/i-have-this-home-work-problem-bit-confusing-algebraically/2576076#2576076