# i have this home work problem bit confusing algebraically,

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n-1)L_{n+1}+\dfrac{(n-2)L_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{5}}{(n-2)L_n+\dfrac{(n-3)L_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}{5}}
\end{equation}

how it becomes
\begin{equation} 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{nL_{n+1}+nL_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{nL_{n}+nL_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}
\end{equation}

1/5 appears missing

Comment: Maybe mention the $L_k,F_k$ are Lucas, Fibonacci numbers and a simple definition of them.

Comment: The numerator is $f(n+1)$ and the denominator is $f(n)$, where $$ f(n) = (An+B)\varphi^n + (Cn+D)\overline{\varphi}^n $$ ensures that the wanted limit is $\varphi$ (the golden ratio).

Comment: yes sir he wanted to removed immediately 5 for us to derive it easy because it is going to golden ratio  i just wanted to know, thanks by the way sir.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a trick question. It's not that the two expressions are supposed to be equal, but rather only the limits themselves are the same. To wit,

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n-1)L_{n+1}+\dfrac{(n-2)L_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{5}}{(n-2)L_n+\dfrac{(n-3)L_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}{5}}
=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{(n-1)L_{n+1}}{(n-2)L_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{L_{n+1}}{L_n}=\varphi
$$

because $L_n>>L_{n-2},F_{n-2}$. Similarly,

$$\begin{equation} 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{nL_{n+1}+nL_{n-2}-F_{n-2}}{nL_{n}+nL_{n-3}-F_{n-3}}
\end{equation}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{L_{n+1}}{L_n}=\varphi$$

Comment: yes i think since L_{n-2} and F_{n-2} is bounded by L_{n}.