# Is this $ \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n-F_{n-1}}$ a bounded sequence with $F_n$ is a Fibonacci sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, bounded-variation

I'm interesting to know about boundedness of the following sequence $ \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n-F_{n-1}}$ with $F_n$ is a Fibonacci sequence  such that I have tried to give its bound , we have $ \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n-F_{n-1}}\geq   \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}\geq 1+\dfrac{F_{n-1}}{F_n} $ using limit on both sides of that inequality we come up to $\lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n-F_{n-1}}\geq  \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{F_n+F_{n-1}}{F_n}\geq \lim_{n\to \infty} \big(1+\dfrac{F_{n-1}}{F_n}) =1+\dfrac{1}{\phi}$ but this it doesn't give any validity about boundedness of the titled sequence ? any help ?

Comment: Note that 
$$
\frac{F_n + F_{n-1}}{F_n - F_{n-1}} = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n-2}}.
$$

Comment: This should help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/132305/42969

Comment: just prove something crude like $1\leq \dfrac{F_n}{F_{n-1}} < 2$ by induction, then you get an upper and lower bound. Anything stronger, you will need to delve into more properties of the Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{F_n + F_{n-1}}{F_n - F_{n-1}} = \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_{n-2}}.
$$
We find that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_n + F_{n-1}}{F_n - F_{n-1}} = 
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\right) \cdot
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}\right) \cdot 
\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_{n-2}}\right) = \phi^3 = 2 \phi + 1,
$$
where $\phi = \frac 12(1 + \sqrt{5})$.
Because this sequence has a limit, it must be bounded.

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\dfrac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}} \to \phi
$$
and so
$$
\frac{F_n + F_{n-1}}{F_n - F_{n-1}}
= \frac{\dfrac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}+1}{\dfrac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}}-1}
\to \frac{\phi+1}{\phi-1}
=(\phi+1)\phi=\phi^2+\phi=2\phi+1
$$
Thus the sequence converges and so is bounded.

Alternatively, and simpler:

We have
$
0 < \frac{x+1}{x-1} < 5 
$
for $x > \frac{3}{2}$. Now $\frac{F_{n}}{F_{n-1}} > \frac{3}{2}$ for $n \ge 5$; this follows easily by induction.