# Reference Request for Linear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Homogeneous, linear ODEs of the form
$$\mathrm{f}^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}\mathrm{f}^{(n-1)}(x)+\cdots+a_1\mathrm{f}'(x)+a_0\mathrm{f}(x)=0$$
where each $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are known to have "solution spaces" of dimension $n$.

For example, the *first order* ODE
$$\mathrm{f}'(x)+\mathrm{f}(x)=0$$
has the solution space $\mathrm{f}(x)=k\,\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ which is spanned by $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$. The *second order* ODE
$$\mathrm{f}''(x)+\mathrm{f}(x)=0$$
has the solution space $\mathrm{f}(x)=a\sin x + b\cos x$ which is spanned by $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

What is the name of this result, and can someone please recommend a good on-line reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the *uniqueness theorem* for linear differential equations. It is usually proved by variation of parameters using Wronskians, as is done below The proof below easily generalizes to higher order. An [analogous proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133673/242) works also for *difference* equations (recurrences).

**Theorem** $\ $  If  $\rm\:f,g,h\: $ are solutions on an  interval I of

$$\rm     y'' =\ p\ y' + q\ y,\ \ \ \ p,q\ \ continuous\ on\ I $$

and the Wronskian $\rm\ \  W = g\:h'-g'h \ne 0\:$ for all $\rm\:x\in I$

then $\,\exists\,$ constants $\rm\: c,d\:$ such that    $\rm\: f  = c\: g  + d\: h\:$ on $\rm\,I.$

**Proof** $\ $ The equations $[0],[1]$ below have unique solution $\rm\:(c,d)\:$ via det $\rm = W \ne 0\:$ on $\rm\,I.$

$\rm[0]\qquad           f\  =\ c\: g \: + d\: h $

$\rm[1]\qquad           f' =\ c\: g' + d\: h'$

Now  $\rm\:q\:[0] + p\:[1]\ $  yields, $ $ on $ $ LHS: $\rm\,\ q\:f+p\:f'\: =\ f'',\ $ similar on RHS below

$\rm[2]\qquad  f'' =\ c\: g'' + d\: h''\ $  via RHS:  $\rm\ \, q\:g+p\:g'\: =\ g'',\,\ \ q\:h+p\:h'\: =\ h''$

$\rm[3]\qquad           0\  =\ c'\:g \:+ d'\:h\:\ \ $  via  $\ \ [0]'-[1]$

$\rm[4]\qquad           0\  =\ c'\:g' + d'\:h'\ \ $  via  $\ \ [1]'-[2]$

$[3],[4]\:$ have solution $\rm\:(c',d') = (0,0),\:$
which is *unique* by  $\rm\ det = W = g\:h'-g'\:h \ne 0\:$ on $\rm\,I.\:$ Therefore $\rm\:c,d\:$ are constants. $\ \ $ **QED**

**References**

L. E. Pursell. [A simple uniqueness theory for ordinary linear
homogeneous differential equations](http://links.jstor.org/sici?sici=0002-9890(196701)74:1%3C47%3E), Amer. Math. Monthly, 74, 1967, 47-50

Variation of Parameters:
https://planetmath.org/variationofparameters
http://ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/204/appsHigherOrder/variationHigher.htm

Marius van der Put. [Symbolic analysis of differential equations.](https://web.archive.org/web/20000926000945/http://www.msri.org:80/activities/programs/9899/focm/soggy/MSRIintro/van_der_Put2.ps)

This post: 2003-11-12, [There are no other solutions... how to prove it?](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/AR2OIaBVlVc/m/Qj3MTAfwjioJ)

---

The above post is excerpted from my [sci.math post on Apr 27 2004](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/193vLqX0SbU/m/-wPOJR0HkXgJ) in the thread "number of indep. soloutions to diffyqs?" (sic)

Answer (score 1):

The solution space $\mathscr X$ of 
$$
\mathrm{f}^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}\mathrm{f}^{(n-1)}(x)+\cdots+a_1\mathrm{f}'(x)+a_0\mathrm{f}(x)=0,
$$
is an $n-$dimensional subspace of $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$.

I can only think of rather advanced textbooks for reference. The one I prefer is the textbook of [Hartmann](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898715105).

The best way to show that $\mathscr X$ is $n-$dimensional is the following:

a. For every $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$ the initial value problem
$$
\mathrm{f}^{(n)}(x)+a_{n-1}\mathrm{f}^{(n-1)}(x)+\cdots+a_1\mathrm{f}'(x)+a_0\mathrm{f}(x)=0,
\quad f^{(0)}=\xi_1,\ldots,f^{(n-1)}(0)=\xi_{n},
$$
possesses a unique, and global solution $\varphi=\varphi(t;\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)$, which is linear with respect to $\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n$, and hence
$$
\varphi(t;\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\xi_k\varphi(t;\delta_{1k},\ldots,\delta_{1n})
=\sum_{k=1}\xi_k\varphi_k(t). 
$$
So, these $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ span $\mathscr X$. They are linearly dependent because
if 
$$
c_1\varphi_1(t)+\cdots+c_n\varphi_n(t)=0, \quad \text{for all $t$},
$$
then 
$$
\varphi(t;c_1,\ldots,c_n)=c_1\varphi_1(t)+\cdots+c_n\varphi_n(t)=0, \quad \text{for all $t$},
$$
and thus  for every $k=1,\ldots,n$ we would have $\varphi^{(k-1)}(0;c_1,\ldots,c_n)=0$.
But
$$
\varphi^{(k-1)}(0;c_1,\ldots,c_n)=c_k.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish that I could give it more that one up-vote. First question: how can we be sure that the solutions must all be smooth functions? (I am inclined to believe the statement because all of my "counter examples" require non-linear operations.)